# ASP.NET Web Api and Data Contracts

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a client for [this public WEB API](https://services.zdravstvo.gov.mk/en/). I am new to this and I was going through [this MSDN tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client). I noticed that there are no Data Contracts defined and i cannot add service reference in my project. In the tutorial in some point it says create this class (Product) as data object that HttpClient will use.

How can i find/create this class when using the public API. In WCF i can add service reference and i will get client classes created from the service data contract. How is this done in Web Api?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem: you've got a web api project which allows you to access your resources on specific urls. `Product` will be one of the resources which you get e.g. on the url `api/product`. In this case just use the `HttpClient` from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in the MSDN article, since there's no defined contract (unlike WCF) you're gonna need to create the appropriate `Types` first in order to be able to consume it using `REST` client.

However, there are some shortcuts you can use, see here:
[Generate Contracts for REST objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939403/generate-contracts-for-rest-objects)

Also, you may find [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) easier to use than the official WebApi client.

Comment: First thank you for your answer. Secondly, how should i create the types? I only have the response XML file, and i've tried to create class that matches the XML format (in terms of class name and properties names). Should I request the classes from the API host or is there another way of creating these types